# How to use dynamic URLs / routes depending of domain?

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I have an e-commerce website that is available in multiple languages through multiple domains. For example: example.com (english), example.fr (french), and so on...
I want to have dynamic URLs like so: `example.com/product/shoes-54`, `example.com/produit/chaussures-54`.
How to declare those routes depending of the domain knowing that /produit must be accessible only on `example.fr` and `/product` only on `example.com` ?

I've tried to declare those routes in a switch case depending of domain.

```php
<?php
$domainName = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : '';
switch($domainName) {
    case 'example.fr':
    case 'www.example.fr':
        $routes->connect('/ajoutez-votre-experience', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'add']);
        $routes->connect('/contact', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'contact']);
        $routes->connect('/conditions-d-annulation', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'refund']);
        $routes->connect('/hote/:slug', ['controller' => 'Host', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['slug']);
        $routes->connect('/experience/:slug', ['controller' => 'Experience', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['slug']);
        $routes->connect('/region/:region', ['controller' => 'Location', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['region']);
        $routes->connect('/region/:region/:region_sub', ['controller' => 'Location', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['region','region_sub']);
        $routes->connect('/region/:region/:region_sub/:city', ['controller' => 'Location', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['region','region_sub','city']);
        $routes->connect('/recherche', ['controller' => 'Search', 'action' => 'index']);
        break;
    case 'example.com':
    case 'www.example.com':
    case '':
    default:
        $routes->connect('/add-your-business', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'add']);
        $routes->connect('/contact', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'contact']);
        $routes->connect('/cancellation-condition', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'refund']);
        $routes->connect('/host/:slug', ['controller' => 'Host', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['slug']);
        $routes->connect('/experience/:slug', ['controller' => 'Experience', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['slug']);
        $routes->connect('/location/:region', ['controller' => 'Location', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['region']);
        $routes->connect('/location/:region/:region_sub', ['controller' => 'Location', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['region','region_sub']);
        $routes->connect('/location/:region/:region_sub/:city', ['controller' => 'Location', 'action' => 'index'])->setPass(['region','region_sub','city']);
        $routes->connect('/search', ['controller' => 'Search', 'action' => 'index']);
        break;
}
```

It's working fine except when I need to get specific URL of a product in my CRON tasks. Since I'm not on a specific domain, I can't "guess" the URL and so the route.

I thought about naming my routes, but I means I need to declare all of theme to get it in my CRON task, which doesn't suit me because I don't want french website to be accessible on `example.fr/product/shoes-54`.

What's the best way to handle multiple domains/langs routes in CakePHP application ? I can't find enough documentation on that unfortunately...

Comment: Seems like a lot of your routes are identical, or am I wrong? I don't understand your need to separate them at all. I also don't really see a need for the URL to be different based on language, I don't think most users will care what the URL itself says.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton this is for SEO purpose.

Comment: [**Routes can be bound to specific hosts**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#matching-specific-hostnames), but what exactly is your task actually trying to do?

Comment: @HJerem both domains are in the same server and respond by the same code? Or there is a application folder for each domain?

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe both domaines are on the same server and respond by the same code.

Comment: @ndm I tried that, but when I define two routes with two domains, no matter what domain I used to access app, it's always the first one that is taken into account.

Comment: You'll have to show what exactly you're doing and what your routes look like, all I can say at this point is that host bound routes do work as expected. Also make sure that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` holds the expected value.

Comment: @ndm `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` holds expected value. I will edit the post with one concrete example.